# What is the effect of gravitational field on an object moving at the speed of light?

Tags: gravity, speed-of-light, relativity, faster-than-light

If a body moving at the speed of light moves towards another stationary body having much greater mass then,this body makes the moving body to accelerate under its gravitational field in such a way that when the moving object is infinitely close to the stationary object its speed is much greater than the speed of light for a infinitely small fraction of a second. Now the object should travel backwards in time, at the start of that infinitely small second. The same process would repeat. This means that the object would appear still in front of the stationary object?

Is this assumption hypothetically right?

Comment: It cant move faster than the speed of light. Accelerating something massive to c requires an infinite amount of energy

Comment: Its an hypothetical assumption.

Comment: Yeah but theres no point in asking a question based on a hypothetical assumption thats not rooted in physics

Comment: Then according to you , Theory of Everything , string theory and multiverse theory developed by some brilliant scientists of the world are not part of physics because they are hypothetical?

Comment: He said "rooted in physics".  The list you give "Theory of Everything, string theory...etc" is rooted in physics and they could be possible.  Moving a massive object faster than light has been deemed impossible.

Comment: If you reformulate your post about an object *near c*, your question can be saved.

Comment: *"Its an hypothetical assumption"* - no, it's not actually that; it's a blatant misuse of reason.  Sure one can show that, e.g., assuming the square root of 2 is a rational number and show that leads to a contradiction thus proving the square root of 2 is not a rational number.  But you're assuming *both* that the laws of physics are valid and not valid, i.e., stipulating that something physics says is impossible is the case and then assume that the same physics you've dismissed to be false are in fact true in order to reach your conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this question is that you are presenting a non-physical situation and asking people to apply physics to it; it's like asking how the color blue would taste. An object with mass cannot move at the speed of light in any reference frame, and no object can move faster than the speed of light in any reference frame unless its mass is represented by an imaginary number; so far, we have not found imaginary mass to be physically possible.

This question is *somewhat* answerable, though. Photons (and other particles of mass $m=0$) do move at the speed of light, and when they get close to very massive objects, like stars, they are influenced by gravity and their trajectory bends. However, the photon does not speed up. It accelerated in the sense that its direction of motion changes, but it still moves at the speed of light regardless.

I hope this helps.